# Does the fact that "Elohim" is plural indicate that parts of the Tanakh hearken from a pre-Jewish polytheistic culture?

Tags: history, tanach, theology, avodah-zarah

(disclaimer, I am a gentile and don't know how to type in square script)

My question applies to the whole Tanakh, but I'm specifically curious about Genesis. Translating strictly literally (ie, etymologically), Genesis 1-3 seem to indicate some sort of polytheism. The Hebrew etymologically translates as "the **gods** said let **us** make man in **our** image", and such plural language recurs pointedly throughout the book.

I'm just wondering what sort of Jewish reflection there has been on this scriptural phenomena? What do the Rabbis (both ancient and modern) say and what sorts of official histories/explanations are put forward? At face value, Genesis seems to be an ancient text produced by a polytheistic culture, and later reinterpreted in line with Monotheism. I'm wondering what opinions and explanations have been put forward by the Jewish tradition itself. So far I have only read Christian theories (which inevitably read the Trinity in) and Academic theories (which double down on the "polytheism" hypothesis)

Comment: Haven't got time now to write a complete answer, but in biblical Hebrew terms indicating ownership, mastery, etc., are often phrased and conjugated in the plural. (Also, for example, the verse you cited is immediately followed by one in with verbs and possessives in the singular - "and He created... in His image.")

Comment: See also several Indo-European languages where the "formal" second-person singular is the same as the third-person plural. And in English, the "royal we".

Comment: It is indeed perfectly possible; but what also has to be taken into consideration is that abstract terms (such as the notion of deity, for instance) ultimately derive from more down to earth concepts; in this particular case, the heavenly ruler(s) are called by a word initially referring to earthly one(s). Since on earth the members of the ruling class contain (far) more than just one single individual, it is therefore not entirely surprising that its celestial counterpart came to be denoted by a plural as well.

Comment: No more than the grammatical gender of my name, "Michah", or that of "Yonah", meant those prophets were women. Names are names.

Comment: "Hearken"? I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Judaism was the first monotheistic revolution that spouted out of polytheism when Abraham recognized that there was only One G-d and that He was One.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason this is confusing is that in Biblical Hebrew, the plural can be used to denote a position of authority. For example, in Exodus 22 the Bible refers to a property owner in the plural even though from context there is only one person. See specifically [Exodus 22:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.22.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> שְׁבֻעַ֣ת יְהוָ֗ה תִּהְיֶה֙ בֵּ֣ין שְׁנֵיהֶ֔ם אִם־לֹ֥א שָׁלַ֛ח יָד֖וֹ בִּמְלֶ֣אכֶת רֵעֵ֑הוּ וְלָקַ֥ח **בְּעָלָ֖יו** וְלֹ֥א יְשַׁלֵּֽם׃
> an oath before the LORD shall decide between the two of them that the one has not laid hands on the property of the other; the owner must acquiesce, and no restitution shall be made.

From context it is clear there are only two people, but the verse still says בעליו, which is a combination of בעל, meaning owner, and the suffix יו, which is plural possessive.

Another example with the word Elohim specifically comes from [Exodus 7:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&ven=The_Rashi_chumash_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en)

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהוָה֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה רְאֵ֛ה נְתַתִּ֥יךָ **אֱלֹהִ֖ים** לְפַרְעֹ֑ה וְאַהֲרֹ֥ן אָחִ֖יךָ יִהְיֶ֥ה נְבִיאֶֽךָ׃
> And the L-rd said to Moses: See, I have made you an **overlord** to Pharaoh, and Aaron your brother shall be your spokesman.

Obviously, Moses was one person, but the plural Elohim is still used.

Yet another example comes from a case of idol worship. By the [Golden Calf](https://www.sefaria.org/Bekhor_Shor%2C_Exodus.32.4.2?lang=en&p2=Exodus.32.4&ven2=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0&w2=Translations&lang3=en) the plural is also used to describe one idol

> וַיִּקַּ֣ח מִיָּדָ֗ם וַיָּ֤צַר אֹתוֹ֙ בַּחֶ֔רֶט וַֽיַּעֲשֵׂ֖הוּ עֵ֣גֶל מַסֵּכָ֑ה וַיֹּ֣אמְר֔וּ אֵ֤לֶּה אֱלֹהֶ֙יךָ֙ יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אֲשֶׁ֥ר הֶעֱל֖וּךָ מֵאֶ֥רֶץ מִצְרָֽיִם׃
> And he received the gold at their hand, and fashioned it with a graving tool and made it a molten calf: and they said, These are thy gods, O Yisra᾽el, which brought thee up out of the land of Miżrayim.

When it comes to pronouns, sometimes they are also plural to grammatically match the noun in the verse, as in the last example, and sometimes they are singular to match the reality. Hebrew is a very flexible language, and there are often multiple ways to say the same thing that are all grammatically correct.

In regard to the case Let Us Make Man, the simplest explanation is that this is the royal we, [see here](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=HaKtav_VeHaKabalah%2C_Genesis.1.26.1-2&lang2=bi) and in the commentary of [Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashbam_on_Genesis.1.26&lang2=bi)

> נעשה אדם - כמו שמצינו במיכיהו בן ימלא במלכים, ובישעיה: את מי אשלח ומי ילך לנו, וגם באיוב.
> “Let us make man” – like we find with Michayahu ben Yimla in Kings, and in Yeshayahu, “Who shall I send, who will go for us”, and also in Job.

There are also deeper meanings, just as every verse has layers of meaning, but the deeper layers cannot and do not contradict the fundamental of our faith, that G-d is [one](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.1.26.1?ven=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann&lang=en&p2=Deuteronomy.6.4&ven2=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang2=en&aliyot2=0&w2=Translations&lang3=en).

> Hear, O Yisra᾽el: The Lord our God; the Lord is one.

Comment: Considering that both terms (*adonai* and *elohim*) are grammatical plurals, the *shema* is not quite as straightforwardly obvious in Hebrew as it is in English, for instance; in fact, it reads almost counter-intuitively.

Comment: Lucian: To an English speaker, using the plural as a form of respect is counter-intuitive, but every language has quirks that seem odd. For example, in Yiddish, it is considered respectful to address someone in the third person, even to their face. So, if you spend time in a yeshiva, you might hear myself and others talking to our Rabbis in the third person. As a native English speaker it can feel weird, but that is a cultural Yiddish thing that transferred over to the English. Learning a book in another language requires the ability to adapt to such differences.

Comment: Many European languages, including my own, possess pronouns of respect based on the grammatical plural, and the royal we is certainly not a linguistic novelty to the British themselves.

Comment: That actually buttresses my point, doesn't it?

Comment: Do Jews possessing perfect eyesight customarily address a single rabbi, no matter how well-respected, as *rabbis* ? My initial point was that the shema is quite counter-intuitive *even in the original Hebrew*, not that it would sound odd when literally translated into English, though that certainly holds true as well.

Comment: Except it isn't. As I showed, in Biblical Hebrew using the plural form to denote authority was not only not odd, it was standard. And when dealing with the highest authority of all- G-d- it becomes even more standard.

Comment: Adonai is NOT a grammatic plural. The nun has a qamatz; in the plural form it would have a patach.

Comment: @N.T.: Were that truly the case, then we would normally expect David, for instance, to have been called *kings*, instead of *king* (similarly for Solomon, etc); or for Samson to have been called *judges*, instead of *judge*; or for Aaron to have been called *priests*, instead of *priest*; or for Moses to have been called *prophets*, instead of *prophet*; etc.

Comment: This rule does not apply to words that are specific in their titles, only to terms of general authority. Elohim just means a position of power, so it can refer to a court, Moses being "overlord" to Pharoah, or G-d. Sometimes the Bible will refer to G-d as the supreme power for clarity, to show that His power is above all others. Thus in Deuteronomy 10:17 "כִּ֚י יְהוָ֣ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶ֔ם ה֚וּא אֱלֹהֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים וַאֲדֹנֵ֖י הָאֲדֹנִ֑ים
For the LORD your God is God supreme and Lord supreme". The same applies to בעל and אדון/adon, which just mean owner or master.

Comment: @N.T.: The head of the generic class of priests is called *high priest*, not *priests*. And the head of a generic group of rabbis is called *chief rabbi*, not *rabbis*. Similarly, the head of the generic class of *judges* would eventually come to be known as *king*, not *judges*. And the Head of the generic class of (heavenly) powers was also called by a special name, the Tetragram; but, unlike the aforementioned cases, He (also) maintains the nomenclature of the generic classes He presides over, being called *powers* and *lords*. One cannot help but notice the rather obvious dissimilarity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are driving at here. High priest is an English term, and so is chief rabbi. They are not Hebrew. The Hebrew word Kohein for priest and shofet for judge are also technically verbs, not nouns. And king is an official title with special halachic status, whereas shofet was an unofficial status. Anyways, the nuances of a foreign language are often confusing to those who have not studied it at length. Arguing with me about how things should be in your opinion won't get you anywhere. I appreciate that theIronKnuckle had the wisdom to ask those with subject matter expertise.

Comment: @N.T.: Not sure why speaking English constitutes a problem; the title of the head of the Jewish priesthood is [Kohen Gadol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Priest_of_Israel), rather than [Kohanim](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/כוהנים), each individual priest being called [Kohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohen). And, in various countries, the title of the head of Jewish Rabbinate is called [Rav haRashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Rabbi), rather than [Rabanim](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/רבנים); etc.

Comment: Like I said, specific titles (kohein, shofet, rabbi, king, etc.) are not pluralized. General terms of authority (ba'al, adon, elohim) are.

Comment: For some utterly mysterious reason, you seem to think that there's something terribly specific about the first set of terms, and something imminently vague about the latter set, when, in reality, their groupings are not particularly objective, and each term encapsulates an array of meanings, which, depending on context, can range from the most general to the most restrictive. At any rate, it would truly help your argument to list a few non-divine terms expressing various forms of authority or hierarchy, wherein the preeminent element is designated by the word's plural form.

Comment: I'm not going to keep repeating myself. I gave the examples you want in my original answer. And just because you say that in your opinion, priest and king etc. aren't specific ENOUGH, that does not affect the actual grammatical rules of Hebrew. To paraphrase Moses, "Who am I that you argue with me?". I did not make the rules, I just showed them to you. You can keep banging your head against the wall if you like, but I won't.

Comment: @N.T.: For at least two reasons, the provided examples appear logically insufficient. Please find more meaningful ones. The second one is especially nonsensical, inasmuch as it would require the use of an seldom-employed singular (at least in prose; Exodus, after all, is not a lyrical text, as the Psalms, where such otherwise infrequent forms abound, nor was it originally written in Aramaic). The surrounding two are also iffy, and the last two do not relate to nouns.

Comment: Look at exodus 21 where the plural of adon is repeatedly used to denote the owner even though from context there is clearly only one person. And the last two were not proofs. You should brush up on your reading comprehension. You show that a little knowledge is a dangerous thing, as you know enough to throw out random points without knowing which points matter or how they connect.

Comment: @N.T.: For whom are you writing your answers ? For God and King Solomon ? If even a person of *some* (small) knowledge cannot comprehend you, what on earth will someone with *no* knowledge *at all* do ? Take cover and run for the hills ? Even if the reasoning might not be flawed, one's way of expressing it might be. Were you talking about [plurals of *excellency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_excellentiae) or [intensity](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/313773225), rather than *majesty* ? Was your *general vs. specific* dichotomy a reference to (the plurals of) abstract nouns ?

Comment: I am sure you could comprehend if you tried; these aren't riddles. I am referring to the concept mentioned in the intro to your second link: For the purposes of this paper, the group of honorific plurals speaking of gods, lords, masters, and beings of prominence, will be considered a separate category. The notion of eminence attributed to an entity conceived of as personal or animate is sufficiently distinct from intensification assigned to an impersonal and abstract idea.

Comment: @N.T.: Your various arguments seem either forced, or weak and unconvincing, especially the ones about **Moses** (was the text supposed to either invent a new Hebrew word just for that situation, or use one infrequently employed ?) and the **royal we** (surely the king wasn't talking to himself there; most likely, he was addressing his courtiers, noblemen, or generals - albeit I do agree that that's how the *royal we* started, since leaders usually speak for the entire group). Thank you for putting up with me thus far, and sorry if I sound like a pestering little kid with all my questions.

Comment: Elohim for those in authority is not as uncommon as you think (see https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.22.27?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009_[with_Onkelos_translation]&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashbam&lang2=en) I just picked a case where it was used for one person to prove that one person could be referred to in the plural when it is a position of authority.

Comment: I'll just add here that I am having trouble understanding Lucian's claims. N.T. brought some really clear examples of where something obviously singular was referred to in the plural. Apparently that happens. How is it a problem that sometimes things _aren't_? Languages are complicated. That still leaves N.T.'s answer in place, he thinks אלהים is such an example.

Answer (score 10):

Often I see ignorant skeptics of the Torah as using this argument to "prove" that Judaism adopted terms from polytheism, but this not at all the case.

The reason why Elohim ends with "-Im", (which *usually* implies a plurality) is because "-Im" is used in this instance in a respective, majestic form.

(the following is a rephrased summary from Isaac Troki's book against christianity, Chizuk Emuna chapter 9)

Genesis 1:1, "In the beginning Elohim [God] created the heaven and the earth." Elohim, ending in a plural form as though it meant Gods, has been interpreted by Christians as an evidence of the plurality in the Deity, consisting of the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost, who are denominated Trinity. The correct terminology of Elohim is as follows: —

Those who know the Hebrew language are aware that Elohim relates not merely to the Supreme Being, but also to angels and human authorities. Manoah, the father of Samson (mentioned in Judges 13:22), after he found that he had perceived "an angel of the Lord," said, "We shall surely die, for we have seen Elohim." In reference to human authorities, we read in Exodus 22:9, "Before the Elohim [judges] the cause of the two men shall be brought, and he, whom the Elohim [judges] shall declare guilty, shall pay twofold unto his neighbour."

We should like to understand how the name of Elohim.....in Exodus 7:1 "Behold I have made you an Elohim to Pharaoh," can be allowed by Christian expounders to allude to a plurality of persons, and represent in a mortal creature a visible Trinity?

The real object in the plural form in Elohim is to *represent authority and power*. This respective plurality is not just used for Elohim, but in words of profane signification. For an example, Adonim (lords) instead of Adon (lord). For instance, Isaiah 19:4, "In the hand of a hard Adonim [lord, literally lords], Genesis 39:20, "And the Adonai [lords instead of Adon, Lord] took him, viz., Joseph,"

The plural form is used instead of the singular in many modern languages (for instance you instead of thou).

Comment: the chapter of Isaac Troki's book can be found here http://faithstrengthened.karaitejudaism.org/FSpart1chapter09.html

Answer (score 9):

R. Judah Halevi addresses this in Part IV of the Kuzari:

> The word has a plural form, because it was so used by gentile idolaters, who believed that every deity was invested with astral and other powers. Each of these was called Eloah; their united forces were therefore, called Elohim.
>
> (Hirschfeld translation p. 198)

So it’s not that it was written by a polytheistic culture, but that it was written against the backdrop of a polytheistic culture.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Maimonides who says that G-d has no body and is one, that “the term image (ẓelem) is applied to the natural form . . . It is the true reality of the thing. . . .  That which was meant in the scriptural dictum ‘let us make man in our image’ was the specific form, which is intellectual apprehension, not the shape and configuration” Guide of the Perplexed 1:1, (Shlomo Pines translation).

Furthermore, El means “powerful.” It is not that the Bible is polytheistic, far from it. G-d is called Elohim (plural) in the Bible because G-d is more powerful than anything else.

Comment: The term elohim is used also for people. When the Bible wants to show that G-d is greater than other powers, it uses the term Elohei haElohim, Ruler over all rulers.

Comment: @N.T. Yes, I forgot to mention that the elohim can also be used for people who are very powerful. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Different names of G-d are used to reflect different aspects.  The Name Elo'him refers to דין judgment.  By it's nature דין is multiplicity.  This is consistent with the word being used elsewhere in the Torah to refer to human judges.  Justice is something which has multiple possibilities - see Ritva Eiruvin re: אלו ואלו that in heaven there are 49 ways each Q is אסור and 49 ways it's מותר.  Likewise (from memory), I think that one of the requirements of the judges is to be able to find 49 ways to prove a pig is kosher (or something similar)

regarding the "let **us" make man" - different explanations are given by the commentators - Rashi, as understood by Maharal understands this to be G-d "talking" to the previously created angels and including them in the decision - asking for their permission - not like a dictator who imposes his will, but rather asking those already created if they are OK with a new addition.

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation given by the kabbalists is based on the fact that the translation of the word אל = El means power (see Gen. 31-29). As such Elo'him means "powers". G'd is called like that because He is the source of ***all powers*** in the world, hence the plural.